# VS Code: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I run a .py file with Sublime Text - everything works perfect.
I run a .py file with cmd - everything works perfect.
I run a .py file with VS Code - for the first 15 seconds code works and everything is ok. If I start a code about 15 seconds after VS Code launch - I see this:

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\Users\wonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38'
  PYTHONPATH = 'C:\Users\wonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38'
  program name = 'C:\Program Files\MSYS2\mingw64\bin\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\MSYS2\\mingw64\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\MSYS2\\mingw64\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
    'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\python38.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\python3.8',
    'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\python3.8',
    'C:\\Users\\wonka\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\python3.8\\lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000017b0 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Also I turned off all extensions except Python - and nothing changed.

Comment: are you combining Win32 and MSYS2 python files?

Comment: I need to change all paths to "...\\AppData\\Local\\..." instead of "...\\MSYS2\\..." ? And if I need, can you tell how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the very left corner of VS Code window is a selector of Python version. Don't know why, but it was not selected. [VS Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tTm9.jpg). You just need to click on it and select Python version.

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling the IDE. Your Extension will not be affected.

Comment: Nothing changes.

Comment: Try reinstalling python.

Comment: In the very left corner of VS Code window is a selector of Python version. Don't know why, but it was not selected. Now everything works perfect. Thanks anyway! :)